# Feature Request: Add tag autocomplete to search bar as well

Tags: feature-request, search

The tags input element when asking a question has a nice autocomplete feature. Is it possible to add the same kind of feature to the search bar once the user starts typing after an open square brace([) that's used to represent tags in search bar currently?

This feature would be very handy for searching tag(s).